# getting name attribute of an anchore with DOM, php

Tags: php, dom, anchor

i have a series of anchros

```
<a name='name1'>something in here</a>
<a name='name2'>something in here</a>
<a name='name3'>something in here</a>
...
```

i want to read the info of the anchor with dom, and do a conditional statement depending on the name.

im getting the content with this code:

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
$file = @$doc->loadHTML($html);
$anchor= @$doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
$m=0;
for ($i = 0; $i<$anchor->length; $i++)
{

   $alumno[$m] = $anchor->item($i)->nodeValue; 
  $m++;


}
```

however i have no idea on how to check the anchor name.

TVM for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get name attribute use getAttribute method:

```
$DomElement->getAttribute('name');
```

in your case:

```
 $anchor->item($i)->getAttribute('name');
```